# Associated Token Account address not correct?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, associated-token-account

I'm trying to access this associated token account:

https://solscan.io/account/DizwsnTVoLCXskwqLMxYCaLqssrArUP2NRQb7dHzDprb

via the following code:

```
const token = new PublicKey("7cYf5Rr6UR7H3cPne3QSFV98pGeYds66iqNiVBpcEnmA")
const owner = new PublicKey("A8y9jwiVu9dXoheXAnDwRnueNEG4XnGf2B77HVnMgWPd")

const ata = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(token, owner);
```

According to solscan, this associated token account has the exact same parameters as my code (same owner, same token).

HOWEVER, my code will return the following address:
`2hKJYn9HyFwhjbM3ZaaAY1cGwVfsDyeG5wqqDLsceSfM`
instead of the on chain address:
`DizwsnTVoLCXskwqLMxYCaLqssrArUP2NRQb7dHzDprb`

I have never seen this and it's happened to multiple people today! Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: Account: ``DizwsnTVoLCXskwqLMxYCaLqssrArUP2NRQb7dHzDprb`` is not an associated token account. Can you explain which program are you interacting to create this account? There isn't much to answer without seeing the actual account creation logic.

Comment: This is the transaction that created the account https://solscan.io/tx/3SjD7xe2JRDaf3FiA5YkDgXFc9AffjFmhgJ4fC7ANAuvh2ZDtYW6TUvou2TfD5TCFHXRnzZsPuQvKHYot6ZYDvqa

The thing is, this account: ```2hKJYn9HyFwhjbM3ZaaAY1cGwVfsDyeG5wqqDLsceSfM``` ideally should be the ata, and should have a balance of 1 because the owner provided owns 1 of that token. Or am I misunderstanding how the method works? Appreciate response btw! Super stuck rn

Comment: The main dillemma: How is it possible that there is two seemingly identical accounts, but only 1 of them has a balance:

https://solscan.io/account/DizwsnTVoLCXskwqLMxYCaLqssrArUP2NRQb7dHzDprb

https://solscan.io/account/2hKJYn9HyFwhjbM3ZaaAY1cGwVfsDyeG5wqqDLsceSfM

Comment: It isn't necessary that the token account has to be ATA. Any keypair can act as a token account. In your case, ``2hKJYn9HyFwhjbM3ZaaAY1cGwVfsDyeG5wqqDLsceSfM`` is a ATA for the given token and owner but the program you interacted with isn't using ATA and creating a new keypair and using it as a token account which was ``DizwsnTVoLCXskwqLMxYCaLqssrArUP2NRQb7dHzDprb``.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to look at the source of get AssociatedTokenAddress, which just invokes findProgramAddress itself (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/9c1ee63f97843d70d0f9c83b7b48e61775945614/token/js/src/state/mint.ts#L162):

```
export async function getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    mint: PublicKey,
    owner: PublicKey,
    allowOwnerOffCurve = false,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): Promise<PublicKey> {
    if (!allowOwnerOffCurve && !PublicKey.isOnCurve(owner.toBuffer())) throw new TokenOwnerOffCurveError();

    const [address] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [owner.toBuffer(), programId.toBuffer(), mint.toBuffer()],
        associatedTokenProgramId
    );

    return address;
}
```

You might try to supply the same seeds and see what you get.

Also note that `DizwsnTVoLCXskwqLMxYCaLqssrArUP2NRQb7dHzDprb` shows that it was created with `create_account`, rather than `create_associated_account`

Answer (score 0):

An unlimited number of token accounts for the same mint can be owned by a public key. For instance, if the token account's address is generated from a newly created keypair or a PDA.

The associated token address is a specific address for a token account that can be used to easily and deterministically find an address for the token account of a specific owner and mint.

In your example, it seems like `2hKJYn9HyFwhjbM3ZaaAY1cGwVfsDyeG5wqqDLsceSfM` is the address for the associated token account, while `DizwsnTVoLCXskwqLMxYCaLqssrArUP2NRQb7dHzDprb` was created through an interaction with a program.